# Integrate view's button with ion auth's user role in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

Suppose I am logged in as admin group, then when I access main_page, there is an 'Export' button. But if I am in members group, it will not be showed up.

Recently, I was thinking to use `if` logic in views. Is it right? Or I still have to use logic on controller?

Comment: if you are doing role-based login then you should do it from the controller. If logic is not and the wrong option but you should follow best practices.

Comment: or you can create a separate view but that's up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check user type in controller and pass it to view

Controller

```
if ($this->ion_auth->is_admin())
{
  $this->data['user_type'] = 'admin';
}
else if($this->ion_auth->logged_in()){ 
   $this->data['user_type'] = 'member';
}
```

Now you can use same variable in view to process your data. Yes you have to write ternary operator/if condition to check

View

```
($user_type == 'admin') ? 'statment_code_here' : 'statment_code_here';
```

In case of multiple conditions check in view, you can use if else statements.

Comment: Thanks, bro. That was I need!